# tableviewcell repeating uibuttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am having a little trouble with buttons on a tableview.

I have a tableViewCell that I customised with 3 buttons. I set the buttons to hidden in interface builder and when the table loads the buttons are hidden as expected.

I then set the hidden property of the tableview to false when didSelectRow is called and hidden.true when didDeselectRow is called. This works fine as well. The problem is the buttons that are set to visible in the didSelectRow are also visible every seven cells down. they keep repeating themselves.

Below is the code that shows the buttons

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ContactsViewCell

            print("Table selected")

                cell.insertEmailButton.hidden = false
                cell.insertPhoneButton.hidden = false
                cell.insertAllButton.hidden = false
                cell.contactTextLabel.alpha = 0.2
                cell.contactDetailTextLabel.alpha = 0.2
        }
```

And this hides them when the tableViewCell is deselected

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ContactsViewCell

        cell.insertEmailButton.hidden = true
        cell.insertPhoneButton.hidden = true
        cell.insertAllButton.hidden = true
        cell.contactTextLabel.alpha = 1.0
        cell.contactDetailTextLabel.alpha = 1.0  
    }
```

I did some research and I learnt it might be the row with the buttons.hidden set to false are being reused by the tableview. But I understand from documentation that the cell being reused is from cellForRowAtIndexPath and not the cell at didSelectRow which is where I am setting the button.hidden to false.

I also tried using the cell.isSelected property in an if else statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to hide and show the buttons but this does not show the buttons at all.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The tableview reuses the view of the cell when the table is scrolled, to save memory. So, for example, when you set the button to visible (inside didSelectRow) and then scroll down the table, the tableview will take the cells that go out of the visible screen at the top and will reuse them at the bottom, to save the overhead of creating new cells, improving performance.

That is why, your previous properties on the cells are repeating.

To get the desired hidden button on scrolled cells, I recommend setting button.hidden to true/false in

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This will set the button to hidden whenever a new row is scrolled into the visible view area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I did use if cell.isSelected in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to set the hidden properties of the button true and false but that just did not show the buttons at all.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about your desired results?

Comment: Its nothing complicated. I just want a tableview with contacts and when a cell is tapped, the title and subtitle fade and the 3 buttons show up. and when another cell is selected, the initial cell reverts its alpha and hides the buttons while the newly selected cell shows the button and fades the titles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the recurring buttons by hiding them when I check if the cell is deselected in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This also means any cell I select will lose its selected status and buttons will disappear when it leaves the view. 
I can live with that.

```
   if cell.selected == false{
       cell.emailButton.hidden = true
       cell.phoneButton.hidden = true
       cell.allButton.hidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView reuses its cell to improve performance. So, you can not do the way you are trying. What we have to do is, like other tableview cell info e.g. title, description, thumb image etc we also need to save the state for buttons in the array. When you want to hide a button for the cell take object at index from the array and change the button state for the button and reload that table view cell. Still if you face problem or feel difficult to understand, please feel free to ask.